# Remove seperation between header/footer/cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem with a line between cell which just doesn't want to go away.

I have tried the following

- Setting the seperator style to `.None` in both code and Interface Builder.
- Increasing the size of the frame `CGRect` for `contentView` by 1px.
- `clipToBounds` to `true` for header, footer and cell.

Whatever I do, I can't seem to ger rid of the lines in between:
[image: Table]

Initiation of my TableView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.clipsToBounds = true
        tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        tableView.separatorStyle = .None

        if let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(LobbySliderHeaderCollectionReusableView.classIdentifier, owner: self, options: nil).first as? LobbySliderHeaderCollectionReusableView {
            tableView.tableHeaderView = nib
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
extension LobbyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categoryChunks.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cellType: GameCollectionCellType!
        if let type = cellTypes[indexPath.item] {
            cellType = type
        } else {
            var isNot: GameCollectionCellType? = nil
            if let lastType = cellTypes[indexPath.item] {
                isNot = lastType
            }

            cellType = GameCollectionCellType.randomItem(isNot)
            cellTypes[indexPath.item] = cellType
        }

        let chunk = categoryChunks[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(GameCollectionViewCell.classIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GameCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureWithGames(chunk)
        let color = waveColors[indexPath.section % 2]
        cell.fillColor = color
        cell.clipsToBounds = true

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let lh = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(LobbyHeader.classIdentifier) as! LobbyHeader

        lh.fillColor = waveColors[section % 2]
        lh.contentView.clipsToBounds = true

        if categories.count > 0 {
            let cat = categories[section]
            lh.title.text = cat.name
            lh.showMore.setTitle("%@ items".localizedStringWithParameters(["\(cat.games.count)"]), forState: .Normal)
            lh.tag = section
        } else {
            lh.title.text = ""
        }
        lh.sizeToFit()

        return lh
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let lf = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(LobbyFooter.classIdentifier) as! LobbyFooter

        let i = section % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0

        let color = waveColors[i]
        lf.waveView.fillColor = color
        lf.waveView.clipsToBounds = true
        lf.contentView.clipsToBounds = true

        let bgColor = waveColors[section%2]
        lf.contentView.backgroundColor = bgColor

        return lf
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

}
```

The lobby header cell, (footer and cell are similar):

```
class LobbyHeader: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var showMore: UIButton!
    var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor() {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = fillColor
        }
    }

    var showGames: (()->())?

    class func nibForView() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: classIdentifier, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        title.text = ""
        showMore.setTitle("", forState: .Normal)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        backgroundColor = BackgroundColors.defaultBackgroundColor
    }

    @IBAction func showMoreAction(sender: UIButton) {
        if let showGames = showGames {
            showGames()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is the red/blue background part of the tableView ? or it comes from the cells background ?

Comment: It is part of the cells. It is set to `cell.fillColor` which in its turn set to `contentView.backgroundColor` with property observer `didSet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell views seems to come from a Xib.
`UITableViewCell` component in xibs often has a 1 pixel margin at the bottom (between the `contentView` and the `tableViewCell` itself).

Try to add a subview in the `cell.contentView` and make it so the background view height is 1 pixel bigger than the contentView.

Comment: The cells are embedded in the storyboard. The only cell which issn't is the tableHeader (which is not shown in the image). The constraint for `contentView` cannot be change though in the storyboard. I tried increasing the size of the view, but don't believe it worked. Will try that workaround again now.

Comment: The `contentView`'s frame can not be changed. This is why you have to use a new subview bigger than the `contentView` of 1 pixel.

Comment: based on your edit you can also try update your cell's `fillColor` setter with `self.backgroundColor = fillColor` and set the `contentView.backgroundColor` to `clearColor()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up clearColor for separators

```
 tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Have you tried to add cell.backgroundColor = color near cell.fillColor = color ?

Comment: Actually… I don't know what are you doing in fillColor's setter, but I'm pretty sure that this problem is not related to separators